# error: 'hash_map' is not a member of 'std'

Tags: c++, g++, hashmap

Here is my 'program':

```
#include <string>
#include <ext/hash_map>

int main()
{
    std::hash_map<std::string, int>  myMap;
}
```

I'm trying to compile it with g++ on Red Hat. Can someone explain why does the compiler complain:

`error: 'hash_map' is not a member of 'std'`

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908581/is-hash-map-part-of-the-stl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hash_map in  is in a different namespace, namely `__gnu_cxx::hash_map`.
More recent versions of hash maps are `std::tr1::unordered_map` or since c++11 `std::unordered_map`