# Convert this recursive function to iterative

Tags: c++, recursion, iteration

**How can I convert this recursive function to an iterative function?**

```
#include <cmath>

int M(int H, int T){
    if (H == 0) return T;
    if (H + 1 >= T) return pow(2, T) - 1;
    return M(H - 1, T - 1) + M(H, T - 1) + 1;
}
```

Well it's a 3-line code but it's very hard for me to convert this to an iterative function. Because it has 2 variables. And I don't know anything about `Stacks` so I couldn't convert that.

My purpose for doing this is speed of the function. This function is too slow. I wanted to use `map` to make this faster but I have 3 variables `M`, `H` and `T` so I couldn't use `map`

Comment: You can always do that by simulating a stack...

Comment: @Angew But I don't know anything about stack :(

Comment: @Angew You mean, simulating recursion by stack. IMO in this case it is the only way to convert this function to iterative - unless one can come with a formula for n-th element of this sequence.

Comment: @user3274384 Then pick up a book on data structures, or one on programming in general. There's a handy list of [good C++ books](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465) here on SO. As your question stands, it's a poor fit for SO. We're here primarily to help with problems you encounter when solving a task yourself, not to solve the task for you.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe it could be done with couple of loops? T seems to count down on each call...

Comment: Why are you wanting to convert it to an iteration?

Comment: @NPE Because of the speed. I need to compute `M` faster.

Comment: @user3274384 Why do you think that iterative will be faster?

Comment: If it's just for speed, then you should use memoization to reduce the number of calls to `M()` since the default case calls `M()` twice.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No function calls?

Comment: Having only 1 reputation doesn't mean that everything you ask is homework.

Comment: @gmorrow: and on a modern CPU, how much overhead is there to do a function call in optimised code? Converting to an iterative method using a manual stack would probably be slower due to the stack's memory management. Personally, I think you'll get an integer overflow before you get excessive computation times. Would help to know the name of the function (looked a bit like the Ackermann function but it isn't)

Comment: @Skizz There is no general formula for this function. So I had to write a recursive function which is really slow.

Comment: @user3274384 Have you considered calculating a look-up table? This will cost you some time in the beginning, but this could pay-off when you need to call `M` many times.

Comment: Put pairs of `H` and `T` in the map. `M` isn't a variable, it's a function.

Comment: Interesting fact about the function: When written in a 2d-table with T as rows and H as columns, the differences between entries from one column to the next form a structure similar to [Pascal's triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle). That is, the differences in a row can be calculated by adding the differences of the adjacent columns from the previous row. I'll leave it to MathOverflow to find out if this can be used to calculate a field in the table directly (but I think it is possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason why this function is slow is because it has exponential complexity, and it keeps recalculating the same members again and again. One possible cure is memoize pattern (handily explained with examples in C++ [here](http://programminggenin.blogspot.nl/2013/01/memoization-in-c.html)). The idea is to store every result in a structure with a quick access (e.g. an array) and every time you need it again, retrieve already precomputed result. Of course, this approach is limited by the size of your memory, so it won't work for extremely big numbers...

In your case, we could do something like that (keeping the recursion but memoizing the results):

```
#include <cmath>
#include <map>
#include <utility>

std::map<std::pair<int,int>,int> MM;

int M(int H, int T){
    std::pair<int,int> key = std::make_pair(H,T);
    std::map<std::pair<int,int>,int>::iterator found = MM.find(key);
    if (found!=MM.end()) return found->second; // skip the calculations if we can
    int result = 0;
    if (H == 0) result = T;
    else if (H + 1 >= T) result = pow(2, T) - 1;
    else result = M(H - 1, T - 1) + M(H, T - 1) + 1;
    MM[key] = result;
    return result;
}
```

Regarding time complexity, C++ maps are tree maps, so searching there is of the order of N*log(N) where N is the size of the map (number of results which have been already computed). There are also hash maps for C++ which are part of the STL but not part of the standard library, as was already [mentioned on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908581/is-hash-map-part-of-the-stl). Hash map promises constant search time (the value of the constant is not specified though :) ), so you might also give them a try.

Comment: I get an error here : `return (*found);` : **no suitable conversion function from "std::pair<const std::pair<int, int>, int>" to "int" exists** Why?

Comment: Oops my bad, getting a bit rusty on C++, fixed the answer.

Comment: used it to calculate M(100,1000), the result spilled over the int (and over long) but it completed in no time. How big the values were you going to give to this function?

Answer (score 6):

you could use `dynamic programming` - start from the bottom up when H == 0 and T == 0 calculate M and iterate them. here is a [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming#Fibonacci_sequence) explaining how to do this for Fibonacci numbers, which are quite similar to your problem.

Comment: So Wikipedia suggested to use `map` for making recursive function faster. But in this case I have actually 3 variables. `M`, `H` and `T`. How can I save them into a `map`?

Comment: @user3274384 - scroll down, after the map solution you have pseudocode for a bottom up iterative one.

Comment: @user3274384 Either use `std::pair<int, int>` or encapsulate `H` and `T` yourself. In the latter case you'll also need to specialize `std::hash` for your wrapper-class.

Answer (score 5):

Check this,recursive and not recursive versions gave equal results for all inputs i gave so far. The idea is to keep intermediate results in matrix, where H is row index, T is col index, and the value is M(H,T). By the way, you can calculate it once and later just obtain the result from the matrix, so you will have performance O(1)

```
int array[10][10]={{0}};

int MNR(int H, int T)
{
    if(array[H][T])
       return array[H][T]; 

    for(int i =0; i<= H;++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j<= T;++j)
        {
            if(i == 0)
                array[i][j] = j;

            else if( i+1 > j)
                array[i][j] = pow(2,j) -1;

            else
                array[i][j] = array[i-1][j-1] + array[i][j-1] + 1;

        }
    }

    return array[H][T];
}

int M(int H, int T)
{
    if (H == 0) return T;
    if (H + 1 >= T) return pow(2, T) - 1;
    return M(H - 1, T - 1) + M(H, T - 1) + 1;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", M(6,3));
    printf("%d\n", MNR(6,3));
}
```

Comment: You may create a class to encapsulate the array, initialization and the `operator()`.

Comment: I'll keep it to OP :)

Comment: you may use one deminsions array.

Comment: @Khurshid The benefit of two dim array, that all your calculations can be done once, and then you get them just by indexes, which looks like impossible with one dim array.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you know the formula for n-th (in your case, (m,n)-th) element of the sequence, the easiest way is to simulate the recursion using a stack.

The code should look like the following:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <stack>

struct Data
{
public:
    Data(int newH, int newT)
        : T(newT), H(newH)
    {

    }

    int H;
    int T;
};

int M(int H, int T)
{
    std::stack<Data> st;

    st.push(Data(H, T));

    int sum = 0;

    while (st.size() > 0)
    {
        Data top = st.top();
        st.pop();

        if (top.H == 0) 
            sum += top.T;
        else if (top.H + 1 >= top.T)
            sum += pow(2, top.T) - 1;
        else
        {
            st.push(Data(top.H - 1, top.T - 1));
            st.push(Data(top.H, top.T - 1));
            sum += 1;
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: This will be slower than a recursive function because cpu-stack memory has negligible overhead for push and pop whereas std::stack has to do heap memory allocations for pushing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is actually slower. For example there is no answer for `cout << M(5, 2)  << endl;`

Comment: The original question I answered was only about conversion from recursive to iterative version and my code does just that :)

Comment: @user3274384 You must of copied something wrong: `M(5, 2)` doesn't recurse in your version, and should only run through the `while` once in his.  Neither should take any noticeable time.  (Globally, of course, his solution is worse than the recursive one, both in execution time and understandability.  You should be able to flatten at least one of the recursions into a simple loop, and keep any intermediate values in a cache of some sort, since the original code recalculates the same value a large number of times.

Comment: +1 your last update was awesome. But probably you missed something because the answer of `M(5,2)` is `26` but in your code it's `33` :(

Comment: @user3274384 https://ideone.com/k5BED3 - note, that I've copied your code 1:1 (modulo function name).

Comment: @Spook Yeah. I meant this `printf("Original: %d Iterative: %d\n", M1(2, 5), M(2, 5));` see. They are different :( Your code works very good and fast but in some cases I get wrong answer.

Comment: Have timed this answer compared to the OP's recursive version over the interval 0<=t,h<25 and the iterative version is 4.5 times slower than the recursive version.

Answer (score 1):

You may calculate using one demintional array. Little theory,

```
Let F(a,b) == M(H,T)
1. F(0,b) = b
2. F(a,b) = 2^b - 1, when a+1 >= b
3. F(a,b) = F(a-1,b-1) + F(a,b-1) + 1

Let G(x,y) = F(y,x)  ,then
1. G(x,0) = x                 // RULE (1)
2. G(x,y) = 2^x - 1, when y+1 >= x  // RULE (2) 
3. G(x,y) = G(x-1,y-1) + G(x-1,y) + 1  // RULE(3) --> this is useful, 
// because for G(x,y) need only G(x-1,?), i.e if G - is two deminsions array, then 
// for calculating G[x][?]   need only  previous row G[x-1][?], 
// so we need only last two rows of array.

// Here some values of G(x,y)  
4. G(0,y)  = 2^0 - 1 = 0  from (2) rule.
5. G(1,0)  = 1  from (1) rule.
6. G(1,y) = 2^1 - 1 = 1,  when y > 0,  from (2) rule.

G(0,0) = 0,  G(0,1) = 0,   G(0,2) = 0,  G(0,3) = 0  ...
G(1,0) = 1,  G(1,1) = 1,   G(1,2) = 1,  G(1,3) = 1  ...

7. G(2,0) = 2  from (1) rule
8. G(2,1) = 2^2 - 1 = 3   from (2) rule
9. G(2,y) = 2^2 - 1 = 3 when y > 0,  from (2) rule.

G(2,0) = 2,  G(2,1) = 3,  G(2,2) = 3, G(2,3) = 3, ....

10. G(3,0) = 3  from (1) rule
11. G(3,1) = G(2,0) + G(2,1) + 1 = 2 + 3 + 1 = 6  from (3) rule
12. G(3,2) = 2^3 - 1 = 7,  from (2) rule
```

**Now, how to calculate this G(x,y)**

```
int M(int H, int T ) { return G(T,H); }

int G(int x, int y)
{   
     const int MAX_Y = 100; // or something else
     int arr[2][MAX_Y] = {0} ; 
     int icurr = 0, inext = 1;

     for(int xi = 0; xi < x; ++xi)
     {
          for( int yi = 0; yi <= y ;++yi) 
          {
            if ( yi == 0 )  
                 arr[inext][yi] = xi; // rule (1);
            else if ( yi + 1 >= xi ) 
                 arr[inext][yi] = (1 << xi) - 1; // rule ( 2 )
            else arr[inext][yi] = 
                arr[icurr][yi-1] + arr[icurr][yi] + 1; // rule (3)

          }
          icurr ^= 1; inext ^= 1;          //swap(i1,i2);
     }
     return arr[icurr][y];
}
```

// Or some optimizing

```
int G(int x, int y)
{
    const int MAX_Y = 100;
    int arr[2][MAX_Y] = {0};
    int icurr = 0, inext = 1;

    for(int ix = 0; ix < x; ++ix)
    {
        arr[inext][0] = ix; // rule (1)

        for(int iy = 1; iy < ix - 1; ++ iy) 
            arr[inext][iy] = arr[icurr][iy-1] + arr[icurr][iy] + 1; // rule (3)

        for(int iy = max(0,ix-1); iy <= y; ++iy)
            arr[inext][iy] = (1 << ix ) - 1; // rule(2)

        icurr ^= 1 ; inext ^= 1;
    }

     return arr[icurr][y];
}
```