# Get an object from a map by reference

Tags: c++

I am trying to get an object inside of a hash_map by reference. It seems simple enough, but I cannot figure out why it doesn't compile. The error is `no match for operator=`. In my mind, I am setting the value of `fooptr` to the address of the found `Foo` object in the map.

```
void FooManager::GetFoo(Foo *fooptr, std::string name){
    std::hash_map<std::string, Foo>::iterator it = this->foos.find(name);
    if(it != this->foos.end()){
       *fooptr = &it->second;
    }
}

Foo *foo = 0;
GetFoo(foo, "test");
```

Comment: If `fooptr` is of type `Foo *`, ask yourself what type does `*fooptr` have.

Comment: There is no `std::hash_map`.

Comment: @Brian Well there is for me.

Comment: @peer_2_peer_2 what standard library do you use?

Comment: @eerorika I am on vxWorks so, whatever they are using.

Comment: Seems like a [std::hash_map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908581/is-hash-map-part-of-the-stl) does exist.

Comment: @TrebuchetMS - The Q&A you linked **explicitly** says the opposite.

Comment: @StoryTeller Perhaps I misread or misunderstood, but referring to [Lightness's second-to-last paragraph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5908859/10239789): "_both MSVC++ and GCC...  place it [hash_map] in the std namespace_". I myself wasn't aware that there was a hash_map container at all. I was merely saying that there _is_ a `std::hash_map` (albeit not necessarily on all implementations). :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confused about pointers.

```
*fooptr = it->second;

Foo foo;
GetFoo(&foo, "test");
```

Declare an object, pass a pointer to that object, dereference the pointer inside the function.

EDIT

Based on feed back below, the answer should be

```
*fooptr = &it->second;

Foo* foo = 0;
GetFoo(&foo, "test");
```

Declare a pointer, pass a pointer to that pointer to the function (a double pointer), dereference the double pointer (to get a pointer) and assign to that a pointer to the map element.

This code is horrendous.

-2 is nothing, i wouldn't worry.

Comment: I feel like I've tried this, it was my original route. It worked but it didn't seem to be obtaining the actual object - more like it was obtaining a copy of it. I'll try again..

Comment: @peer_2_peer_2 Of course it's obtaining a copy. Sounds like you need a double pointer.

Comment: I guess I just don't get it? I have an object living inside a map. That object has an address. So why does declaring a pointer, and then passing it to a function, and then setting the value of that pointer to the address of the object, not work?

Comment: to use `Foo * FooManager::GetFoo(std::string name)` is must more practical to get a pointer to, of course return nullptr if not found

Comment: Because the pointer in your function is only a copy of the pointer outside your function. If you want to change a pointer, you need to pass a pointer to the pointer, same as if you want to change an integer you need to pass a pointer to the integer. (references work as well).

Comment: Or do what bruno suggests which is equivalent but a little easier to understand.

Answer (score 3):

After reading the comments in john's answer I think I understand your problem. Call by pointer is also call by value. You copy the pointer address. You can call by reference to pointer:

```
void FooManager::GetFoo(Foo *&fooptr, std::string name){
    std::hash_map<std::string, Foo>::iterator it = this->foos.find(name);
    if(it != this->foos.end()){
       fooptr = &it->second;
    }
}

Foo *foo = 0;
GetFoo(foo, "test");
```

Now `fooptr` is a reference to a pointer. When you change the address (value) of `fooptr`, you also change the address (value) of `foo`.

Comment: That works, too. I think I'll just return the address itself.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong... shouldn't it be `fooptr = &it->second;` (without the star) instead?