# How do I get old C++ code which uses hash_map to build?

Tags: c++, stl, hashmap, std

Apparently, STL precursors of the C++ standard library used to include hash-based containers in a header file named `hash_map.h` (specifically, I guess, a `hash_map` container). But - the [C++ standard library does not have a `<hash_map>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908581/is-hash-map-part-of-the-stl); and AFAIK `unordered_map` is not exactly the same thing.

Now, I'm trying to build this old codebase and I've just noticed it includes `<hash_map.h>`.

What should I do to get the code to build, assuming I'm using Devuan Beowulf (~= Debian Buster) Linux on an AMD64 machine?

Notes:

- I don't want to replicate a complete 10-year-old development environment; this codebase should eventually be buildable with my (or any modern) Linux distribution.
- I'm willing to:

  - Make minor changes to the code.
  - Install some distribution-appropriate packages.
  - Install something under `/usr/local`

  in decreasing order of preference.

Comment: What would happen if you did a global search and replace for `hash_map<` and replaced with `unordered_map`.  Likewise replace `#include <hash_map.h>` with `#include <unordered_map>`.  Wouldn't it just work?  Maybe?

Comment: @selbie: The code doesn't build right now for other reasons. I want to know whether what you suggested is _supposed_ to work, or known to generally work; and if not, what the caveats are.

Comment: There's at least one web page suggesting that hash_map is synchronized with respect to threads. Assuming you aren't relying on the hash_maps to be accessed by multiple threads without a lock, I would think you are going to be ok.  Even if you brought in an alternate implementation for hash_map, you'd still have to test your code in a similar manner.

Comment: What are you hashing? There are topnotch free algorithms, better tested than most would expect. Standard libs are often lazy. Hashing an `int` is a no-op which results in poor spread. There are people skilled enough to do this properly. Inspiration: http://mostlymangling.blogspot.com/

Do you need some hashing that fits into an old scheme or a replacement that works really well?

Checkout the blog and the references to "random". It's plug and play. The fun part is that you can actually `constexpr` many situations even though it takes time to compile :)

Comment: If you need a `<hash_map>` header with functions to make the rest of the code happy, I think I can provide it. Just provide the signatures you need.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how much work you're willing to do, and what your future plans for this code base are.

You could:

- find an old compiler that has `<hash_map>` and install that. I'd suggest something like a 10 year old version of gcc.
- Find a different chunk of code that does what you want.
- Change all the the uses of `hash_map` into `unordered_map` and then figure out what else needs to change.

Comment: Only option 3 is relevant. But - can you guarantee that `unordered_map` behaves like `hash_map` (ignoring implementation details of course)?

Comment: No; you can't guarantee that they behave identically.  I'm confident they behave "similarly", but that's not the same. If I thought that they were identical, I would not have added "figure out what else needs to change" to my answer

Comment: I don't suppose there's a description somewhere of how they differ... ? Also - Boost ASIO seems to have a hash_map; wouldn't that work?

Comment: @einpoklum The SGI documentation ( http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_map.html ) got taken down, but someone seems to be hosting it on their website ( http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/stl/hash_map.html ). The documentation may help in figuring out how close the two are.

Comment: If you going to do a port to some other implementation of hash_map, which isn't standardized, you might as well do the work to just convert to <unordered_map>.

Comment: @selbie: I was hoping maybe I could just replace the inclusion with an inclusion of the Boost header, and a `using` statement...

Comment: @selbie: Actually, possibly 0, since I haven't found any instantiations for now, making the question somewhat theoretical. But - suppose there were several. What then?