# What causes a hash_map error and how can I fix it?

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile and run this GUI code:

```
#include "Simple_window.h" // Get access to our window library
#include "Graph.h" // Get access to our graphics library facilities

int main()
{
    using namespace Graph_lib; // Our graphics facilities are in Graph_lib
    Point tl{ 100, 100 }; // To become top left corner of window
    Simple_window win{ tl, 600, 400, "Canvas" }; // Make a simple window
    Polygon poly; // Make a shape (a polygon)
    poly.add(Point{ 300, 200 }); // Add a point
    poly.add(Point{ 350, 100 }); // Add another point
    poly.add(Point{ 400, 200 }); // Add a third point
    poly.set_color(Color::red); // Adjust properties of poly
    win.attach(poly); // Connect poly to the window
    win.wait_for_button(); // Give control to the display engine
}
```

Source of headers and code files: http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/PPP2code/

I get the hash_map error

```
Error (active)    E0035    #error directive: <hash_map> is deprecated and will be REMOVED. Please use <unordered_map>. You can define _SILENCE_STDEXT_HASH_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS to acknowledge that you have received this warning.    ConsoleApplication1    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\hash_map    21
```

What causes an hash_map error and how can I fix it?

Comment: The link is broken: *"403. Forbidden. You don't have permission to access /Programming/PPP2code/ on this server."*

Comment: PPP2 probably refers to "[Programming: Principles and Practice using C++ (Second Edition)](https://www.stroustrup.com/programming_support.html)", Addison-Wesley 2014, ISBN 978-0-321-99278-9"

Answer (score 1):

`hash_map` is an old API predating the [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) specification, where they decided the name for that container was `unordered_map`.  You need to switch to using that name instead.

Comment: It was never in standard C++ at all. C++11 didn't change it. The thing comes from the STL, i.e. pre-C++98.

Comment: FWIW, don't use `unordered_map` if you *need* performance.  It's basically a `std::vector<std::list<T>>` under the hood so your basically guaranteed to always have a/many cache miss(es) trying to access any element.

Comment: @NathanOliver It'll be heavily workload dependent, I agree in general that a robin-hood hashing implementation is superior.

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly what it says.

The header `<hash_map>` is not standard, but [came from the actual STL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5908859/560648). Though [it currently remains available on your platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/hash-map-class?view=vs-2019), it's "deprecated and will be REMOVED".

You should do what the message says and switch to modern tools like `std::unordered_map`. Unfortunately that means straying from your source material.

I'm guessing the error itself comes from within fltk (none of Bjarne's code seems to include that header, though I only scanned through it quickly). These examples are very, very old.

You can learn C++ from [a modern book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), instead.

In the meantime, and again as the error message says, you can define `_SILENCE_STDEXT_HASH_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS` (in your project settings under "Preprocessor Definitions") to acknowledge this for now.

---

Similar question:

- [```hash_map``` Error with Stroustrup's GUI examples from chapter 12 of his book Programming Principles and Practices Using C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59557742/560648)

Comment: True, the error comes from std_lib_facilities.h : `template<> struct hash<String>`

Comment: And this, folks, is why we shall not call the C++ Standard Library "the STL"!

Comment: @LucasGras No, that's something else.